# How do I copy a list of lists and append it to a new list in python?

Tags: python, list, copy, append

I'm working on a function that is to create a copy of a list with sublists in python. It is supposed to then append the copy to an empty list named new_puzzles. But when I call the function i'm getting way to large of a return. Below is my original list, current code, and output any help is appreciated!

**Original list**

[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]]

**Code**

```
def copy_puzzle(puzzle):

new_puzzles = []
new_puzzles = puzzle.copy()

for i in range(len(puzzle)):
    new_puzzles.append(puzzle)

return new_puzzles
```

**Output**
[[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]], [[5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 9, 0, 7, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0], [6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 8, 0], [0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1, 9, 0], [0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8], [0, 7, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0]]]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The function is supposed to return the new_puzzles list

Comment: That's clear, and the function indeed does that. What value do you expect `new_puzzles` to have?

Comment: The output might just be a copy of the original?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm new to python as a whole. What i know is that this is to return a copy of the original puzzle for a sudoku. It specifically calls for a deep copy of the puzzle list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think this may be the case: you are using a for loop to loop through the length of the list however long this is. This might be causing the output to be too long as you are appending this list to the new one x number of times. Solution could be to just remove the for loop and have the list append to the new list once.

Solution:

```
def copy_puzzle(puzzle):
    new_puzzles = puzzle.copy()

    return new_puzzles
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing the list of lists to a function it is not necessary to make a copy of it. If you want to append the given list of lists to an empty list the solution would just be:

```
def copy_puzzle(puzzle):
    return [puzzle]
```

However I'm not sure if that is the desired functionality. As Mureinik said, the expected output would be helpful.